# How to remove, but not delete, podcast episodes?

Tags: podcasts, itunes-match, podcasts.app

I want to remove podcast episodes on my iPad to free some space. But I don't want to lose them nor do I want to remove them from the saved episodes. I want to "re-cloud" them basically. 
Is here any way to do this without factory resetting the iPad regularly?

Comment: What is "re-cloud" ?

Comment: I want them returned to to state where they are available to download (through iTunes Match) but not stored on the device. Basically having a cloud icon next to them (hence re-cloud).

Answer (score 1):

Podcasts are not stored on iTunes Match. So basically you can remove them from your iPad by deleting them in your podcast app and re-download them as long as the producer of the podcast keeps this episode online.